# How can I get this photo back to directory?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know a cliche but I am trying to make a kanye quote app where it shows new Kanye quotes as shown below:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


def get_quote():
    response = requests.get(url="https://api.kanye.rest")
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    quote = data["quote"]
    canvas.itemconfig(quote_text, text=quote)


window = Tk()
window.title("Kanye Says...")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=414)
background_img = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
canvas.create_image(150, 207, image=background_img)
quote_text = canvas.create_text(150, 207, text="Kanye Quote Goes HERE", width=250, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"),
                                fill="black")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

kanye_img = PhotoImage(file="kanye.png")
kanye_button = Button(image=kanye_img, highlightthickness=0, command=get_quote)
kanye_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Every time I click but I am being told that the photo is not in my directiory even though it is in the same folder. I don't believe it's to do with the code but I've moved them out and then back in but it still won't work.
Anyone else ever faced the issue and can help?
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0paFh.png)
It may be because the photos corrupted but I can open it on desktop.

Moved into different folders then back.
Re-named it then tried again.
I can't find the original photo online so I can't re download

Comment: Python doesn't look in "the same folder" - it looks in the _current working directory_ which may or may not be the same folder.

Comment: If you have a look at the photo I am within my directory and folder.

Comment: I left this code the exact same (which I created about a month ago) and have now come back to it to make changes and it's no longer working

Comment: It is working for me. Try to provide full path to your files, e.g.: `c:\temp\kanye.png`

Comment: This is from the 100 days of code course. I remembered doing this too.

If you use `file="kanye.png"` you should have the .py file in the same folder, otherwise use the full path of the file.

Comment: Yes it is from the course

Comment: I have tried around and I'm not sure what caused it previously but it is fully functioning as it was previously.